# Reading multiple strings using sscanf() based on a delimiter

Tags: c, string, scanf

I have string having multiple words separated with commas like

```
char str[]="K&R,c89,c99,c11";
```

I am trying to read the first 2 words into a separate character arrays using `sscanf()`.

```
sscanf(str, "%[^,] s%[^,]s", str1, str2);
```

I intended `sscanf()` to scan through `str` till reaching a `,`, store it to `str1`, continue scanning till another `,` and store into `str2`.

But value is being stored only into `str1` while `str2` seem to be having garbage.

I tried removing the space between the `%[^,]s`s if that was of any significance but it made no difference on the output.

What am I doing wrong? Or is this not possible for multiple words?

I've heard of doing something like this with `strtok()` but I was wondering if `sscanf()` could be used for this.

Comment: `strtok()` is destructive as it changes the string and leads to unexpected behavior. Using `sscanf()`is therefore much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duh.. It took me a while to see it. Get rid of the `s` in your format string. The *character class* `[...]` takes the place of `s` and by putting `s` in there, you are forcing `sscanf` to look for a *literal* `s` in `str`, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 8

int main (void) {

    char str[]="K&R,c89,c99,c11";
    char str1[MAX] = "";
    char str2[MAX] = "";

    if (sscanf(str, "%[^,],%[^,]", str1, str2) == 2)
        printf ("str1 : %s\nstr2 : %s\n", str1, str2);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sscanfcomma
str1 : K&R
str2 : c89
```

Also, consider protecting your arrays from overflow with, e.g.

```
    if (sscanf(str, "%7[^,],%7[^,]", str1, str2) == 2)
```

Comment: We have all beaten our heads into the wall over something similar -- don't worry, it won't be the last time `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin *We have all beaten our heads into the wall...* And then we stopped using `scanf()`...